# How to order all my films with rating in CLIPS?

Tags: class, sorting, clips

I have to do a recommandation project of films. I have 1 user, and my program ask him questions to complete the slots and then giving a rate to the films. When the user has answered all the questions I have to make a rule that have to be the last one to be executed to order my films. The problem is that I don't know any method to order my classes.

```
(defclass Pelicules
(is-a USER)
(role abstract)
(slot puntuacio (type INTEGER) (default 0))
(slot plorar (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))
(slot riure (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))
(slot edat (type INTEGER))
)
```

I have a slot to show the five films wiith more rating (pelicules), and I though about sub him 1 for every film showed, making the sistem shows 5 films.

```
(defclass Usuari
(is-a USER)
(role concrete)
(pattern-match reactive)
(slot edat (type SYMBOL) (default nil))
(slot sexe (type SYMBOL) (default nil))
(slot estatCivil (type SYMBOL) (default nil))
(slot vehicle (default nil))
(slot social (default nil))
(slot emocionalment (default nil))
(slot esportista (default nil))
(slot tipusMusica (default nil))
(slot professioEscolliries (default nil))
(slot tempsLliure (default nil))
(slot viatge (default nil))
(slot festaPrefe (default nil))
(slot pasarTemps (default nil))
(slot pensar (default nil))
(slot pelicules (type INTEGER) (default 5))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I meant Objects. Finally testing I find the answe.

```
(defrule order
(declare (salience -1))
?obj <- (object (is-a Usuari) (pelicules ?s&:(> ?s 0)))
?obj2 <- (object (is-a Pelicules) (puntuacio ?p))
(not (object (is-a Pelicules) (puntuacio ?q&:(> ?q ?p))))
=>
(send ?obj canvia-pelicules 1)
(send ?obj2 print)
(send ?obj2 delete)
)
```